# pyqt5: move a function to another file and then call it with qtimer every X sec

Tags: python, function, pyqt, pyqt5, qtimer

I have a GUI app which is getting trough APIs some random information (weather, current time, currency exchange rates, ...)
As my *app.py* file is getting messy I want to move the individual functions to different files (*weather.py*, *currenttime.py*, *exchange_rates.py*) to keep my *app.py* clean.

Here is a code sample only containing the clock:

```
import json
import requests
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
import sys
import time
from time import localtime, strftime, gmtime

class bulletindesktop(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(bulletindesktop, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("bulletindesktop.ui", self)  # loads the UI

        # Initializes the Clock(updates itself every sec)
        clock = QtCore.QTimer(self, interval=1000, timeout=self.showTime)
        clock.start()
        self.showTime()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def showTime(self):
        # Clock
        time = QtCore.QTime.currentTime()  # gets current time
        timeText = time.toString("HH mm" if time.second() %
                                 2 == 0 else "HH:mm")  # changes time to string,
        self.labelTime.setText(timeText)
        # Date
        self.labelDate.setText(strftime("%d.%m.%Y", localtime()))
        # Day
        self.labelDay.setText(strftime("%A", localtime()))

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])  # initializes pyqt
win = bulletindesktop()  # adds Example class to "win"
win.show()  # shows window
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

From here I want to move the `showTime` function into a file called *currenttime.py* in a folder called *modules*. However, I think I tried every not possible way by now.

How can I move the function to another file and call it from there?

Full code can be found here: https://github.com/netspherecyborg/BulletinDesktop